# What is the space of pairwise distances associated with $n$-tuples of points on a circle?

Tags: differential-topology

Let $\mathbb{T}^n$ be the $n$-dimensional torus with coordinates $\mathbf{z}=(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ (so that each $z_i\in[-\pi,\pi)$ is a coordinate on a one-dimensional circle). For each $\mathbf{z}\in\mathbb{T}^n$, define $R(\mathbf{z})$ to be the set of pairwise distances between the coordinates $z_i$, i.e. each $R(\mathbf{z})$ is a set of $n\choose 2$ numbers $d_{ij}$ with $d_{ij}\in[0,\pi]$.

Define $\mathcal{M}^n$ as $\mathbb{T}^n\setminus \sim $ where $\mathbf{u}\sim \mathbf{v}$ iff $R(\mathbf{u})=R(\mathbf{v})$ (as unordered sets).

Is $\mathcal{M}^n$ some well-known object? As a manifold, are there some "nice" coordinates on it? (For $n=2$ this is just the interval $[0,\pi]$ but already for $n=3$ it seems to be somewhat nontrivial).